# Compensation eligibility for delayed baggage (50 hours), merely for the trouble, with British Airways (international)

Tags: uk, luggage, compensation, delays

Had an international flight to the UK, for tourism purposes, with British airways.
Came there for about 3 days, and baggage was delayed for about 50 hours before I finally received it. a day later already had a flight to another country, so the whole incident was very stressful.

Am I eligible for any compensation, merely for the inconvenience?

[Their site says:](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/lost-and-damaged-baggage/making-baggage-claims)

You can claim for the following items:

- essential items such as toiletries and basics when a bag is delayed,
  up to a reasonable value (please keep hold of your receipts as we'll
  need these to assess your claim)
- damage to your baggage*
- damage to your contents
- missing contents
- baggage reported as missing for more than 21 days

[Site also says:](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/legal/notice-of-liability)

In case of baggage delay, the air carrier is liable for damages unless it took all reasonable measures to avoid the delay or it was impossible to take such measures. The liability for baggage delay is limited to 1,288 SDRs [approximately £1,365; EUR1,600; USD 1,774].

This thing happend to other people too, heard it was due to computer system issues.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/180091/30703

Comment: Your travel insurance probably covers a delay of this length too.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to delays affecting your arrival at the destination in countries covered by EC261 and similar legislation, there are no blanket compensation rules for luggage delays (so nothing like “over X hours of delay you get Y pounds/euros/dollars”).

The Montreal Convention is what governs indemnification, and as hinted at in what they told you, you can claim for stuff you had to buy while you waited for your luggage. It does go a lot further than just “toiletries” though, but it needs to be reasonable, justified and proportional, and there’s a limit on the total amount.

[This article from Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/travel-rewards/montreal-convention-luggage/) has more details on the topic.